# office.js DialogAPI with messageChild method

Tags: office-js

Currently `dialogAPI` has `messageParent` method that will allow only child window to communicate with parent(Task-pane). Is there any scope for `messageChild method` in future that can pass some data/message to child window without closing it?

Currently we are relying on javascript's [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) objects method for communication between two windows

Answer (score 2):

You can send messages from the parent window to the child window in at least 2 ways:

1. Pass it as a query parameter on the URL that you pass to displayDialogAsync.
2. Store the information in localStorage with script on the parent page and have script in the child page read it.

If you have a suggestion for a new API, please go to [Office Developer User Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/). Thanks!

Comment: Hi Rick, Thanks for the suggestions. Our data is too large for query parameter and we cannot use localStorage due to security concerns

Comment: To echo Richi's comments, please do add your idea/vote in user voice. We might add a sendMessage API in the future that might help.